# PrimeNg Menu Click

Tags: angular, primeng-menu

MenuItem of primeng has a parameter called command that is a function to be executed when its item is clicked.
However, I want to open another menuItem on click of item of previous menuItem or on hover of particular item it should open another menuItem.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNg MenuItem has a property `expanded` that you can set to `true` and enable the visibilty of a submenu

Comment: I don't want submenu. I want another MenuItem popup to be open on click of item of previous menu.